# MFC: how to create Skinnied Dialog with transparent PNG as backrownd (and instead of window chrome)?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog, window

So here is a grate [small, readable MFC sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26887/A-user-draw-button-that-supports-PNG-files-with-tr). But its background is a solid image; I wonder how to create a transparent PNG as app backround?

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic methods to alter the non-client ("chrome") area of windows.

[Layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx), were introduced in Windows XP - and allow varying levels of window effects. The technique here is to add the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style to a window - which prevents the `WM_PAINT` (in MFC `CWnd::OnPaint`) from operating. Instead, layered windows are painted by the application calling `UpdateLayeredWindow`, providing a DIBSection filled with pre-multiplied 32bpp data.

Windows Vista introduced the [Desktop Window Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx), that composes windows before painting them to enable desktop alpha effects. Using the DWM API to get alpha effects is not as customizable as a PNG, but is still quite attractive.

Both techniques run into problems as child window painting is not alpha aware - layered windows simply don't paint child windows so you need to enumerate and paint all child controls to offscreen surfaces manually. DWM windows do paint child controls - but none of the standard windows controls available to native Apps has been modified to be alpha aware.

Ironically, .NET WinForms apps, on the surface appear to simply wrap the standard windows common controls, but actually all the standard controls have been redeveloped for .NET, and they paint correctly when placed in the 'glass' area of windows.

Comment: well I ended up with [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42032/Perfect-Semi-transparent-Shaped-Dialogs-with-Stand) ... seems to work for me...